# Diaplay posts using Sql sub query

Tags: mysql

I am building a small social network for my department.

I have the homepage as a place where you can make comments and your friends can comment on it.

I have **4 tables** ...allposts_tb, friendship_tb,response_tb and signup_tb..

The **allposts_tb** collect the updates and post made by people it has the following columns (`all_id(PK)`,`name`,`comment`,`time`)

The **friendship**_tb as the columns (`friend_id(Pk)`,`myname`,`newfriend`,`status`)

The **response_tb** as columns(`id(Pk)`,`name`,`response`,`all_id(Fk)`,`time`)

The **signup_tb** as columns (`signup_id`,`lastname`,`firstname`,`email`,`password`,`country`,`profilepicture`)

I can display comments made by people easily using the sql query below

```
 SELECT allposts_tb.all_id,allposts_tb.name,allposts_tb.comment, allposts_tb.time,
friendship_tb.myname,friendship_tb.newfriend,signup_tb.firstname,
signup_tb.lastname,signup_tb.email,signup_tb.profilepicture,
allposts_tb.expand   
FROM allposts_tb,friendship_tb,signup_tb
WHERE allposts_tb.name = friendship_tb.newfriend
 and friendship_tb.myname=colname and
 allposts_tb.name=signup_tb.email
ORDER BY allposts_tb.all_id DESC
and colname=$_SESSION['MM_Username']
```

Well am having problems displaying responses made by people on a particular comment right below the comment...just like replicating facebook's page.Immediately you say something,it should be displayed right below the comment...
I know am meant to use a sub query. right inside the query i gave you guys..have read a lot of web pages but cant get it to work...please help me...

Comment: Since your users don't have direct access to `$_SESSION['MM_UserName']` its not a huge risk, but  your code still is vulnerable to [SQL injection]
(http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should use 
the appropriate method of your database library to escape your data prior to 
making the query.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a second query similar to your first query except using response_tb instead of the allposts_tb table.  Then put a UNION ALL statement in between the two queries, combining the results.  At the end you could put an ORDER BY clause and order by all_id and then time.

Just replace the "comment" field with "response" in your query from the response_tb.

The SQL would most likely look something like this:

```
SELECT allposts_tb.all_id,allposts_tb.name,allposts_tb.comment, allposts_tb.time,
friendship_tb.myname,friendship_tb.newfriend,signup_tb.firstname,
signup_tb.lastname,signup_tb.email,signup_tb.profilepicture,
allposts_tb.expand   
FROM allposts_tb,friendship_tb,signup_tb
WHERE allposts_tb.name = friendship_tb.newfriend
 and friendship_tb.myname=colname and
 allposts_tb.name=signup_tb.email
and colname=$_SESSION['MM_Username']

UNION ALL

SELECT response_tb.all_id,response_tb.name,response_tb.response, response_tb.time,
friendship_tb.myname,friendship_tb.newfriend,signup_tb.firstname,
signup_tb.lastname,signup_tb.email,signup_tb.profilepicture,
response_tb.expand   
FROM response_tb,friendship_tb,signup_tb
WHERE response_tb.name = friendship_tb.newfriend
 and friendship_tb.myname=colname and
 response_tb.name=signup_tb.email
and colname=$_SESSION['MM_Username']
ORDER BY all_id DESC, time desc
```

Comment: Thank you Tom...but am really new to sql and i dont understand your answer....Could you please help me ?

Comment: yeah thanks....am having undefined index :response in C:\wamp\www\Yheeps\homepage\shownewcomment.php on line 345 and this is what i have on line 345......  <?php echo $row_comment['response']; ?>